# Is it possible to have the name of a list inside of another list in python?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, statements

So basically I am not sure why my if statement is not working and I think it might be because I have list names in my lists but I am not sure. Any help in appreciated, thanks!

```
def calc_fare(colour, distance, zonestart, zoneend):
    farelist = [colour, distance, zonestart, zoneend]
    red = [2.00, 2.50, 4.50, 6.50]
    silver = [1.80, 2,30, 4.10, 5.80]
    blue = [0.90, 1.15, 2.05, 2.90]
    gold = [3.60, 4.60, 8.20, 11.60]
    z1 = ['z2', 'z3', 'z7']
    z2 = ['z1', 'z3', 'z6']
    z3 = ['z1', 'z2', 'z4', 'z6', 'z7']
    z4 = ['z3', 'z5', 'z6', 'z7']
    z5 = ['z4', 'z6']
    z6 = ['z2', 'z3', 'z4', 'z5']
    z7 = ['z1', 'z3', 'z4']
    if zonestart in zoneend:
        return colour[2]
    else:
        return "test if statement failed"

def main():
    print (calc_fare((str(input('Please enter colour'))), (float(input('Please enter distance'))), (str(input('Please enter starting zone'))), (str(input('Please enter ending zone')))))
    #print(calc_fare("silver", 8.5, "z3", "z6"))

main()
```

Comment: You have strings in your lists; they may look just the same as the names but Python doesn't make that connection.

Comment: Also your lists are recursive, you will have to put a bit more effort into this ;) (although Python is awesome enough to actually support that)

Comment: None of the lists is recursive..?

Comment: Use dictionaries instead of lists; you'll barely have to change the code. In a dict, the `key` and `value` can both be a string, so you could do `dict[value]`, and you're actually accessing the `key` that that `value` refers to.

Comment: I'm very glad to say your comment despite being short turned out to be the most useful. I used dictionaries as you said and completed the assignment as per instruction. Thank you very much. Your reply has helped more than you can imagine! 

+10000

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are declaring a bunch of local variables in your `calc_fare` that you are not using at all; let's start by removing those:

```
def calc_fare(colour, distance, zonestart, zoneend):
    if zonestart in zoneend:
        return colour[2]
    else:
        return "test if statement failed"
```

the `distance` param is also not used:

```
def calc_fare(colour, zonestart, zoneend):
    if zonestart in zoneend:
        return colour[2]
    else:
        return "test if statement failed"
```

What you're left with is just a function that returns the 3rd item in the value referred to by its 1st parameter if the value of the 2nd param is contained in its 3rd param.

Given this information, you should try to reconsider what you're asking in the first place.

**As to putting lists inside of other lists; if you have this:**

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [l1, 4, 5, 6]
```

what you end up with is equivalent to:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [[1, 2, 3], 4, 5, 6]
```

not

```
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

if you want to "splat" `l1` into `l2`, you need to:

```
l2 = l1 + [1, 2, 3]
```

or

```
l2 = [-3, -2, -1] + l1 + [4, 5, 6]
```

or whatnot.

**As to referring to already defined variables**

`'foo'` as well as `"foo"` creates a string containing the text "foo"; `foo` refers to a variable whose name is "foo". If you don't understand that, I STRONGLY suggest you get a book on Python (or any other language for that matter) for the absolute beginner.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = ['l1', 4, 5, 6]
```

will give you exactly that: a list containing 4 items: the string "l1" followed by integers 4, 5, 6..

Comment: Oh but I dont want to put a list inside of another actually I just want to put the name of the list inside of another list? Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "name of a list"? the name of the variable containing that list? Well that's just a string now, isn't it—why would you not be able to put that in any list you like?

Comment: ...and just in case you didn't realize: the name of the variable storing (or, really, *pointing to*) a particular object/value at any given time, is in no way known by the object/value pointed to by the variable—the same list instance/object can be referred to by 2 or more variables, each bearing a different name, and this would in no way be visible by the list itself. And my apologies if I'm telling you something you already know.

Comment: Ok so I tried this input (silver, 8.5, z2, z6) but the if statement does not work even though z2 is in the z6 list. Why is that?

Comment: Did you actually read my answer, @user1814771? Or if yes, did you understand what I said and the implications thereof? Just please look at the reduced version of your code, and ask yourself why that is—i.e. why did I eliminate all those `z1` and `z2` etc assignments.

Comment: All right so I got rid of farelist like you said because it was unecessary, but I will actually need distance if the zonestart and zoneend are the same; I just haven't added that part into my code yet.  If it makes it more clear this is what I am trying to accomplish: Assignment 03 https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs115/assns/Assignment03.pdf

Comment: As for the z1 and z2 assignments and why you removed them I shall look into that now.

Comment: All I'm saying is that the `z*` variables are never used anywhere at all—you cannot refer to variables defined inside a function from outside the function when calling it... so basically you have to make it completely clear to yourself what variables are and what they arent... they aren't some sort of magical definitions that "just work" and that you can use anywhere throughout your program—they have visibility/scope, and there's only one way to refer to them, and that's *not* quoted strings.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what you mean by `zonestart in zoneend` or `return colour[2]`, or `farelist` or in fact anything else in that function. Nor have you even told us what you're trying to compute in the first place.

Comment: I got a solution using dictionaries. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish what you want with `locals()`, however it is not paricularaly good practice. I would recommend storing the actual link to the object instead of just what they are called.

EDIT: as an example

```
>>> z1 = ['z2', 'z3', 'z7']
>>> z2 = ['z1', 'z3', 'z6']
>>> locals()[z1[0]]
['z1', 'z3', 'z6']
```

Comment: For some reason, I get the feeling `locals()` is *not* what the OP needs... :) (P.S. not my downvote)

Comment: not only what he needs, but I don't even see how that's helping him.

Comment: I have just included an example showing how you would use locals() to accomplish what the poster seems to be asking for. I don't think they should use it, I was just adding that because it was possible.

Comment: @PeterMichealLacey-Bordeaux: read his comments—that's not at all something he's asking for: he's trying to refer to e.g. variable `z2` defined inside of the function at the call site of the function... which is why my first comment: the OP has absolutely no experience whatsoever with variables, and it's most probably his nth venture into programming (n <= 3).